# Windows Scheduled Tasks via GPO on different versions of Windows

Tags: windows, group-policy, scheduled-task

I am working on a project involving multiple isolated Windows domains. Each domain is unique with differing version of Windows clients and differing versions of Windows Server running as Domain Controllers. Some of these Windows versions may be out of date including Server 2000, Server 2003, Server 2008, XP and Vista.

I need to run a scheduled task on various Windows computers in each of these domains by pushing it out via Group Policy. The task needs to run on each computer as the local SYSTEM account.

I plan to expand my test environment soon, but currently I am running a Server 2012 R2 DC and editing the group policy on it.

When I create the Scheduled Task GPO via "Scheduled Task (At Least Windows 7)" and select Windows 7 in the "Configure For" option and then configure my task and update Group Policy on the clients it runs fine on Windows 7 and Windows 10 systems. It does not run on Windows 8 systems.

I am able to create another Scheduled Task using the same settings and do Item Level Targeting and Select Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 as the OS and it runs on those OSes as well.

I am not however able to get this to run on Vista or XP. I've tried using the other option of just "Scheduled Task" while creating the scheduled task GPO, but it does not seem to apply to Vista and XP machines.

The other wrinkle I have that I have not begun testing for is that I may run into domains that are running versions of Windows other than Server 2012 R2 as their domain controllers, and I don't know how that will effect this.

Any help with the most straight forward way to setup scheduled tasks via GPO to run on various versions of Windows is appreciated, including if that will change based on the version of Windows where the Scheduled Task GPO is being created.

Comment: have you checked whether the group policy is applied or not in windows xp /vista pcs ? if its a user level policy try , gpresult /Scope User /v and if its a pc level  gpresult /Scope Computer /v . Just to make sure the group policy is applied yet not working or may be its not applied at all

Comment: if it is applied , yet not working may be the latest policies are not working anymore in xp .. as a work around you can put it in a .bat in your login scripts .. and target for windows xp vista.. using wmi queries..

Comment: Login script-----> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431705%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770908(v=ws.11).aspx  wmi query to select/target os-------------------> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947846(WS.10).aspx